# How to properly set up a filtered Gmap view

Tags: views, google-maps

I have Gmap set up, and the maps are showing correctly on the individual nodes. The "Node Locations" link in the sidebar is also showing them correctly. However, I want to filter this view, and can't quite figure out the correct way to set this up. The closest I've gotten so far has all the pushpins in the upper left corner, rather than distributed across the map. Pointers would be most welcome. Thank you!

Comment: http://www.symphonythemes.com/content/how-display-location-info-gmap-drupal

Comment: Interesting, but dated. Also, it seems to show how to set up locations for nodes and how to display them on the built-in node map. My setup already does this: what I'm trying to figure out is how to create a filtered view showing only the nodes that are tagged as currently active.